# Swift 3: Designable table view cell

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I'm having some trouble with visualise my custom table view cell in the interface builder.

Does anyone know how to make a `@Designable` table view cell?

When I import my custom table view cell in a storyboard with a tableview, only the background color is working. When I try to set the text of the label inside my table view cell, the interface builder crashes.

My setup is called from the following methods:

```
- override public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)

- required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

I think it's because my label isn't initialised at this moment?

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ProgressHeaderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: - View methods

    override public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.setupNib()
    }

    // MARK: - NSCoding
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupNib()
    }

    func setupNib(){
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

//        self.headerLabel.text = "Hello world"
    }

}
```

---

**Updated code:**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CustomTableView: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

// MARK: - View methods
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    self.awakeFromNib()
}

override public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    //check that there are no current subviews
    if self.subviews.count == 0 {
        self.setupNib()
    }
}


// MARK: - NSCoding
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    //check that there are no current subviews
    if self.subviews.count == 0 {
        self.setupNib()
    }
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    if headerLabel != nil {
        self.headerLabel.text = "Hello world"
    }
}

func setupNib(){
    let bundle = Bundle(for: CustomTableView.self)
    guard let customView = bundle.loadNibNamed("CustomTableView",owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CustomTableView else {
        return
    }
    customView.frame = self.bounds
    self.addSubview(customView)
 }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add tbaleView data source methods.

Comment: The data source methods is added. I'm trying to set the label inside my designable UITableViewCell, which mean I got a IBOutlet to my label? Shouldn't it be initialised then?

Comment: Can you post some code for more clarification?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question. 
The xib file update the background color, but when I'm trying to update the text of the headerLabel, the IB builder crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of possible issues you can look into here. First, whenever you create a custom view you will need to associate it with the xib file name.

```
func setupNib(){
    let bundle = Bundle(for: ProgressHeaderTableViewCell.self)
    guard let customView = bundle.loadNibNamed("NAME_OF_XIB_FILE_GOES_HERE",owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ProgressHeaderTableViewCell else {
         return 
    } 
    customView.frame = self.bounds
    self.addSubview(customView)
}
```

Also, whenever I work with xib files, I do any view setup within the `awakeFromNib()` method after checking to make sure one of the expected elements is not nil.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    if headerLabel != nil {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.headerLabel.text = "Hello world"
    }
}
```

Finally, I've only been able to get IBDesignables to work when I wrap the setup functions with the a check that there are no current subviews:

```
override public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    //check that there are no current subviews 
    if self.subviews.count == 0 {
        self.setupNib()
    }
}

// MARK: - NSCoding
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    //check that there are no current subviews 
    if self.subviews.count == 0 {
        self.setupNib()
    }
}
```

P.S When I was learning this, I found this blog post super helpful. You may want to read through it yourself to get a handle on IBDesignable and custom views. http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still can't get the usage of my custom cell to work in the IB, but now it doesn't crash anymore. The current running code is updated in the original post ^^. It only update my custom view in the storyboard, when i used prepareForInterfaceBuilder(), as shown above, where I can set the background color to blue. But at this moment the label is nil.

Comment: Don't call awake from nib, that method will be called for you.

Comment: If I remove: 
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        self.awakeFromNib()
    }

Nothing is rendered in the IB

Comment: have you implemented the init(frame: CGRect) method?

Comment: Alright, I think I found the issue why it wasn't called. I removed the if self.subviews.count == 0 {
        self.setupNib()
    }. And then it updated my IB. Thank you for your help!